# Ember.js remove from store on successfull destroy

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use `destroyRecord` in a delete action like this

```
App.PostController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    destroy: (post)-> post.destroyRecord()
```

But this is removing the post from store even if the request fail.
I have a solution but i dont like it.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    destroy: (post)-> 
      post.destroyRecord().then(
        () =>, #success
        (error) => post.rollback() #error
      )
```

I prefer the opposite behavior, on success remove the post from store, on fail do nothing or show an error message. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use `deleteRecord` in combination with `save` to make this transactional.

Per Ember docs `destroyRecord` is

> Same as deleteRecord, but saves the record immediately.

Here's an example of using `deleteRecord`.  See bullet point #8:

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/migrating-from-ember-data-0-13-to-1-0-0-beta-1-my-findings/2368